# Align a button to the right-end of a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to get the below "sign in" button to be on the right end of my sign-in form but I cannot achieve it for some reason.

How I want it to look:

[image: Figma Design]

What it currently looks like:

[image: Code]

What my frontend code looks like:

```
    <RuxContainer className="container">
      <div slot="header" className="header-container">
        <h3 className="first-header-item">LOGO</h3>
        <RuxClock timezone="Z"></RuxClock>
        <RuxMonitoringIcon status="normal"></RuxMonitoringIcon>
      </div>
      <div className="body-container">
        <form className="rux-form">
          <h2 className="body-sign-in">SIGN IN</h2>
          <h6>Measure your success in the Space Force!</h6>
          <div className="sign-in-inputs">
            <rux-input
              id="email"
              placeholder="Email@astro.com"
              label="Email"
              type="email"
              ruxblur="{handleValidation()}"
            ></rux-input>
            <rux-input id="pw" label="Password" type="password"></rux-input>
          </div>
          <div className="sign-in-helper-functions">
            <rux-checkbox class="checkbox">Remember me</rux-checkbox>
            <h2 className="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</h2>
          </div>
        </form>
        <rux-button className="sign-in-btn" type="submit">
          Sign in
        </rux-button>
      </div>
    </RuxContainer>
```

What my CSS looks like:

```
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.body-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.rux-form {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 430px;
}

sign-in-btn {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

I am new to CSS so any help there would be greatly appreciated as well, thanks!

Comment: You need a `.` before the button class name: `.sign-in-btn {align-self: flex-end;}`.

Comment: still nothing has changed

Comment: Okay, I also tidied up your code to be closer to actual frontend code, so I posted my test code below to show what I mean.

Comment: no your code does not work

Comment: Have u tried float: right?

Comment: yes, James B found the solution for me though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Problem

Your `rux-button.sign-in-btn` is a child element of the `.body-container` element, which is using flex-box to align your form to the center. Hence when aligned to the end by your CSS, [it is making that alignment based on its parent element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#nested_flex_boxes): `.body-container`.

## Solution

Make your `<form>` element also a flexbox container, and then `align-self: end` should behave as expected on the button.

[Nesting of flexbox container elements like this is totally normal.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#nested_flex_boxes)

### Style

```
.rux-form {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 430px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sign-in-btn {
  align-self: end;
}
```

### Markup

```
<form className="rux-form">
  ...
  <rux-button className="sign-in-btn" type="submit">
    Sign in
  </rux-button>
</form>
```

An alternative option if you'd rather not use `display: flex` on the form itself is to create a flexbox container that occupies the full width of form which  has the button as a child and then you can justify the button to the right with respect to that container - which has the forms width.

### Style

```
div.sign-in-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  width: 100%;
}
```

### Markup

```
<form className="rux-form">
  ...
  <div class="sign-in-container">
    <rux-button type="submit">Sign in</rux-button>
  </div>
</form>
```

## Extra

Since you asked for additional CSS advice, note that this nested flexbox container strategy could also be used handle the alignment of the "Remember me" and "Forgot Password" controls.

```
.sign-in-helper-functions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not really "frontend code", as it doesn't work in the browser. If you tidy it up a bit, and add a `.` in front of `sign-in-btn`, it does work:

```css
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.body-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.form {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 430px;
}

.sign-in-btn {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<RuxContainer class="container">
  <div slot="header" class="header-container">
    <h3 class="first-header-item">LOGO</h3>
    <RuxClock timezone="Z"></RuxClock>
    <RuxMonitoringIcon status="normal"></RuxMonitoringIcon>
  </div>
  <div class="body-container">
    <form class="form">
      <h2 class="body-sign-in">SIGN IN</h2>
      <h6>Measure your success in the Space Force!</h6>
      <div class="sign-in-inputs">
        <input
          id="email"
          placeholder="Email@astro.com"
          label="Email"
          type="email"
          ruxblur="{handleValidation()}"
        ></input>
        <input id="pw" label="Password" type="password"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="sign-in-helper-functions">
        <checkbox class="checkbox">Remember me</checkbox>
        <h2 class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</h2>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button class="sign-in-btn" type="submit">
      Sign in
    </button>
  </div>
</RuxContainer>
```

Comment: not exactly what I want, please look at Figma design image of what I want

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.body-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.form {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 430px;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:end
}
```

```html
<RuxContainer class="container">
  <div slot="header" class="header-container">
    <h3 class="first-header-item">LOGO</h3>
    <RuxClock timezone="Z"></RuxClock>
    <RuxMonitoringIcon status="normal"></RuxMonitoringIcon>
  </div>
  <div class="body-container">
    <form class="form">
      <h2 class="body-sign-in">SIGN IN</h2>
      <h6>Measure your success in the Space Force!</h6>
      <div class="sign-in-inputs">
        <input
          id="email"
          placeholder="Email@astro.com"
          label="Email"
          type="email"
          ruxblur="{handleValidation()}"
        ></input>
        <input id="pw" label="Password" type="password"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="sign-in-helper-functions">
        <checkbox class="checkbox">Remember me</checkbox>
        <h2 class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</h2>
      </div>
       <div class="btn">
     <button class="sign-in-btn" type="submit">
      Sign in
    </button>
    </div>
     
    </form>
   
  </div>
</RuxContainer>
```

Comment: Answers should contain some explanation. Please see [answer] and take the [tour].

Comment: This answer does not look like the Figma design I posted above, please review attached images before rushing to post something to get points...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
align-self : end;
```

or you can use:

```
left-margin : auto;
right-margin : 0;
```